# Остовное дерево (MST) с максимальным количеством ребер одинакового веса

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дерево

Добрый день. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Дан взвешенный неориентированный связный граф `G`. Веса рёбер постоянны. Необходимо реализовать алгоритм нахождения общего веса остовного дерева для `G`, удовлетворяющего следующим условиям:

- Остовное дерево должно иметь *максимальное количество ребер с одинаковым весом* (фактическое значение веса у таких рёбер не имеет значения);
- *Общий вес связующего дерева должен быть минимизирован.*
  Это означает, например, что остовное дерево `T1` с весом `120`, которое имеет не более `4` ребер с одинаковым весом (и вес каждого из этих рёбер составляет `15`), должно быть предпочтительным по отношению к остовному дереву `T2` с весом `140`, которое имеет не более `4` рёбер с одинаковым весом (и вес каждого из этих рёбер составляет `8`).

На данный момент реализован алгоритм Борувки по поиску `MST` для графа, но не ясно, нужно ли для решения поставленной проблемы выполнять какие-либо операции после обнаружения `MST`, или лучше модифицировать сам алгоритм `MST`-поиска.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи? Заранее спасибо!